# Cambiar una palabra de un parrafo desde un input con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

quisiera saber como puedo cambiar la palabra de un parrafo que vienen desde un texto que ingresamos desde un input con un ID.

en este codigo la palabra cambiada debe reemplazar a la que dice JUAN que esta dentro de la etiqueta span

> Cita en bloque

```
<span id="sustantivo_1">Juan</span>


<!-- Cambia el sustantivo propio 1-->
                <label for="sustantivo_1">Cambia el Sustantivo propio 1:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="ingresa_sustantivo" size=50><br>
                <br>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#ingresa_sustantivo').keyup(function() {
                var sustantivo = $("#ingresa_sustantivo").val;
                $("#sustantivo_1").text(sustantivo);
                $("#sustantivo_1").css("background", "#c2eeff");

            });
 });
    </script>
```

Comment: Saludos. Te falto agregar el error o el resultado (de momento) que no corresponde a lo esperado. Te comento que donde obtienes `sustantivo` hace falta a `val` los paréntesis (debe ser `val()`) y donde asignas a `sustantivo_1` prueba (en vez de `text(sustantivo)`) con `html(sustantivo)`.

Comment: carajo, no me di cuenta de eso antes de publicar.. pense que era otro error... muchas gracias.. con text(sustantivo) igual funciona :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#ingresa_sustantivo').keyup(function() {
                var sustantivo = $("#ingresa_sustantivo").val();
                $("#sustantivo_1").text(sustantivo);
                $("#sustantivo_1").css("background", "#c2eeff");

            });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
<span id="sustantivo_1">Juan</span>
</h1>

<!-- Cambia el sustantivo propio 1-->
<hr>

                <label for="sustantivo_1">Cambia el Sustantivo propio 1:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="ingresa_sustantivo" size=50><br>
                <br>
```